# Alternative way to call a variable in ggplot2 (R)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to call a variable from a list using ggplot2? I am trying to create an interactive/all purpose script for a colleague.

This is how I usually plot something:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = variable1)) + geom_histogram()
```

But for this script, I want something like:

```
plot_this_variable <- "variable1"
ggplot(df, aes(x = plot_this_variable)) + geom_histogram()
```

Is this possible? If so, how?

Edit:

Solution, use aes_string() instead of aes().

Comment: You can use aes_string(), which takes strings for the variable names instead of bare expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aes_string` has been deprecated, you can either use `sym` with `!!` or use `.data` pronoun.

```
library(ggplot2)
#Using `sym`
ggplot(df, aes(x = !!sym(plot_this_variable)) + geom_histogram()

#Using .data
ggplot(df, aes(x = .data[[plot_this_variable]])) + geom_histogram()
```

However, `.data` is now the preferred way.